# If for all $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset X$ such that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|a_n\|<\infty$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, $X$ is Banach

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space such that for all $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset X$ satisfying $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|a_n\|<\infty$, it follows that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges to a limit in $X$. Show that $X$ is a Banach space.

I had been asked that question (to be precise, I have been asked to show "if and only if") whereas all I managed to prove is the other direction. I sincerely have got no idea how to compare a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset X$ that is Cauchy to a series that converges absolutely. Could you give me a hint? I have been looking for such a question and come by nothing, following which, I suspect, the statement is either wrong or alternately immediate and simple.

Comment: I just came by one. Many times it is only after I post a question that I actually find a duplicate, unfortunately

Comment: To write a norm use "\|" instead of "||".

Comment: Hint:  Take a Cauchy sequence.  Then use the Cauchy criterion to choose a subsequence where adjacent elements in the sequence are very close to each other.  Then form a telescoping sum (sum of the differences between the adjacent elements)